# Why the rotation looks wrong?

Tags: edit-mode

I'm a beginner in a blender and use version 2.82.
Why the rotation looks wrong ?
It can be seen that it is not 45 degrees.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you think is wrong? How it should be?

Comment: If you look from Top - you should rotate around Z...

Comment: Well, depends on what you want to achieve. Right now the rotations are on the X and Y coordinates, but you're looking straight down on the Z axis. I suggest changing between front, left and top ortographic views and tweak the angles until you get the desired result. Basically eyeballing it.

Comment: I may be wrong, but in my opinion the sun's beam must pass through the center of the coordinate system.

Comment: If you use rotation on Z it will pass through the Center..

The rotation axis is perpendicular to your view axis

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand what you are saying to me :). I used the coordinate axes incorrectly. Now things are ОК.